# PHP QODBC Connect Remotely

Tags: php, mysql, linux, odbc, quickbooks

I am working on a project that needs to connect to Quickbooks via php. using odbc_connect, I can connect to our remote server you QRemote. We have the host the program on a Linux server without a GUI.

Is there a way to connect the remote server using QODBC driver instead of QRemote? The program is going to look to see the tables in quickbooks and mirror the data to a MySql database.

Answer (score 0):

You can install MS SQLServer on Server that have Quickbooks and then create link between SQLServer and odbc_connect (QODBC) (creating LinkedServer on MS SQLServer). [QODBC with SQLServer](http://qodbc.com/qodbcsqlserver.htm)

Instead of using QODBC Driver, you can use SQL Anywhere Driver (ODBC) for connect to DBMS of Quickbooks (Sybase).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest referring to the following:

PHP: http://qodbc.com/links/2892 & http://qodbc.com/links/2623

Accessing QuickBooks data remotely - http://qodbc.com/links/2517